# Issues with multiple audio files in HTML onclick

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am creating an online instrument that has 10 keys, each with a recorded sound to play on click. At the moment it is only playing the first sound and I can't work out what I need to do in my code to get the other audio files to play. I have looked at multiple links to try and solve this but nothing has worked!

```
<h1> Click to Play
```

```
<script>  function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
             }
 </script> <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473 /Low_2.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%202.mp3" ></audio>

 <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/Low_3.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%203.mp3" ></audio>


 <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/Low_5.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%205.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/Low_6.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%206.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/Low_1.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%201.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High_2.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/high%202.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High_3.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High%203.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High_5.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High%205.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High_6.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play()"><audio id="audio" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/high%206.mp3" ></audio>

<img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/High_1.jpeg' alt=''>



</body>
<html>
```

Comment: minimize extra spaces in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sent Id to the javascript function or use different id

**first solution** :

```
<h1> Click to Play </h1>

<script>  function play(id){
   var audio = document.getElementById('audio'+id);
   audio.play();
             }
 </script> <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473 /Low_2.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play('1')"><audio id="audio1" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%202.mp3" ></audio>

 <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/Low_3.jpeg' value="PLAY"  onclick="play('2')"><audio id="audio2" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%203.mp3" ></audio>    

</body>
<html>
```

**Second Solution:**

you can use jquery like this:

```
<h1> Click to Play </h1>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function() {
        $(this).first('audio').play();
    });

});

</script>
 <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473 /Low_2.jpeg' value="PLAY" ><audio id="audio1" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%202.mp3" ></audio>

     <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/Low_3.jpeg' value="PLAY" ><audio id="audio2" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2124473/low%203.mp3" ></audio>    

    </body>
    <html>
```